# How do I reset the model matrix in 3Ds Max?

Tags: 3ds-max

In 3ds max, I need to reset the model matrix without changing the position of all vertices. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I didn't know that the model matrix was called a "pivot".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "model matrix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the hierarchy tab, click on "Affect Pivot Only" and move the pivot to 0,0,0 .